# Angular - ngx-datatable celltemplate not populating data

Tags: angular, ngx-datatable

In my Angular-12, I am using **@tusharghoshbd ngx-datatable celltemplate.**

I have the component as shown here:

component:

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.isLoading = true;
  this.siteInfoService.getAllSiteInfo1()
    .subscribe(
      data => {
        this.allSiteInfoList = data.results.info;
        console.log(data);
      },
      error => {
        this.store.dispatch(loadErrorMessagesSuccess(error));
        this.isLoading = false;
      }
    );

  this.options = {
    loader: true
  }
  this.columns = [{
      key: 'id',
      title: '<div class="blue"><i class="fa fa-id-card-o"></i> ID</div>',
      width: 60,
      sorting: true,
      align: {
        head: 'center',
        body: 'center'
      },
      vAlign: {
        head: 'bottom',
        body: 'middle'
      },
    },
    {
      key: 'name',
      title: '<div class="blue"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Name</div>',
      width: 100
    },
    {
      key: 'email',
      title: '<div class="blue"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> Email</div>',
      align: {
        head: 'left'
      },
      width: 100,
      sorting: true
    },
    {
      key: 'address',
      title: '<div class="blue"><i class="fa fa-building"></i>  Address</div>',
      width: 300,
      sorting: false,
      align: {
        head: 'left',
        body: 'right'
      },
      noWrap: {
        head: true,
        body: true
      },
      cellTemplate: this.addressTpl
    },
    {
      key: 'website',
      title: '<div class="blue"><i class="fa fa-calendar-times-o"></i> Website</div>',
      width: 60,
      sorting: true,
      align: {
        head: 'center',
        body: 'center'
      }
    },
    {
      key: 'zip',
      title: '<div class="blue">Action</div>',
      align: {
        head: 'center',
        body: 'center'
      },
      sorting: false,
      width: 80,
      cellTemplate: this.actionTpl
    }
  ]

}
```

HTML:

```html
<ngx-datatable tableClass="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" [data]="data" columns]="columns">
  <ngx-caption>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-6 ">
        <b>
                      <i class="fa fa-table" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                      Site Info. List
                  </b>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-6  text-right">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
                          <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> Add New Data
                      </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ngx-caption>



  <ng-template #addressTpl let-row let-rowIndex="rowIndex" let-columnValue="columnValue">
    {{columnValue.name}}, {{columnValue.email}}
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template #actionTpl let-row let-rowIndex="rowIndex" let-columnValue="columnValue">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" (click)="edit(row)">Edit</a> |
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" (click)="remove(rowIndex)">Delete</a>
  </ng-template>

</ngx-datatable>
```

I expect it to populate the data from the JSON response of the restful api, but no data is displayed except the column header caption.

But when I did console log for:

console.log(data) in

```
    data=>{
      this.allSiteInfoList = data.results.info;
      console.log(data);
    },
```

I have this:

```
{
  "message": "Site Infos. Successfully Retrieved.",
  "error": false,
  "code": 200,
  "results": {
      "infos": [
          {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Lamptey",
            "email": "example@email.com",
            "address": ddsdsdsd,
            "website": www.marlamp.com,
            "phone1": 2549099887766,
            "phone2": null,
            "phone3": null,
            "site_name": null,
            "site_logo": null,
            "site_favicon": null,
            "created_by": 0,
            "updated_by": 0,
            "created_at": null,
            "updated_at": null
          }
      ]
    }
}
```

How do I resolve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some issues/typo errors that would like to point out.

### Issue 1: Miss out the opening square bracket for `columns]="columns"`

> site-info.component.html

```
<ngx-datatable tableClass="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" [data]="data" columns]="columns">
```

**Fix for Issue 1:**

> site-info.component.html

```
<ngx-datatable tableClass="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" [data]="data" [columns]="columns">
```

---

### Issue 2: Use `[data]="allSiteInfoList"` instead of `[data]="data"`

> site-info.component.html

```
[data]="data"
```

> site-info.component.ts

```
this.allSiteInfoList = data.results.info;
```

As you assign the value to `allSiteInfoList`, you should refer your data source as `allSiteInfoList`.

**Fix for Issue 2:**

> site-info.component.html

```
[data]="allSiteInfoList"
```

---

### Issue 3: Use `data.results.info` instead of `data.results.info`

In your JSON result, it shows `infos` not `info`. Saw that you access the wrong property name.

Would suggest defining the **interface** for your response result as the blueprint.

```
{
  ...
  "results": {
      "infos": [
      ..
    ]
  }
}
```

> site-info.component.ts

```
this.allSiteInfoList = data.results.info;
```

**Fix for Issue 3:**

> site-info.component.ts

```
this.allSiteInfoList = data.results.infos;
```

---

### Issue 4: Pagination not work correctly (As reply to Post Owner's comment)

The `ngx-datatable`'s pagination is not working correctly with these errors:

1. Showing NaN to NaN of 1 entries
2. Showing page number of 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

As you miss out the Input property binding for `[options]`.

You have to add `[options]="options"` so the pagination will work.

**Fix for Issue 4:**

```
<ngx-datatable tableClass="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" 
  [data]="allSiteInfoList" 
  [columns]="columns" 
  [options]="options">
```

[Sample solution on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-datatable-angular-9rvttr)

Comment: I have these few questions:   1. Why still showing Showing NaN to NaN of 1 entries instead of 1 of 1.   Secondly. for the pagination why is it still showing 1,2,3,4... since its only one page.    Lastly, 3. How do I customize my own ID as row + 1 instead of it coming from the DB.      Thanks

Comment: Hi @user11352561, this is due to you miss out `[options]="options"` in your `ngx-datatable`. I have updated my answer and the solution.

Comment: Hello @YongShun - I really appreciate. But my last questions   -  How do I customize my own ID as row + 1 instead of it coming from the DB. Thanks

Comment: I think you can do ID increment with `pipe(map)` in the service. You may look at the [site-info.service.ts](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-datatable-angular-unueqt?file=src/app/site-info.service.ts).